# How to set remember_token NULL in laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I have an application in laravel which have a Users table with a column `remember_token`and the User model has the three function mentioned here: http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26

`getRememberToken()`, `setRememberToken($value)`, `getRememberTokenName()`

In my login form, I have email, password and a remember me checkbox field. What I want is if user ticked that `Remember Me` checkbox, then only laravel should remember the user, else it should set the column as NULL.

But at the moment it is remembering it all the time, and I don't know how to set it to NULL.

My doLogin function code is below:

```
public function doLogin()
{
    $rules = array(
        'email'    => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:7'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } else {

        $remember = Input::get('remember');

        $userData = array(
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        );

        // attempt to do the login
        if (Auth::attempt($userData, true)) {
            return Redirect::to('/');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('login')->with('loginError', 'Incorrect email or password.');
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me what modification I need to make so that it set remember_token as null in database when remember checkbox is not ticked by user.

Comment: The second parameter of the `Auth::attempt()` method can be used to set whether you want to create the remember_me cookie or not. Your hard coding it to `true` instead of using the input assigned to the `$remember` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users)

> If you would like to provide "remember me" functionality in your
>   application, you may pass true as the second argument to the attempt
>   method, which will keep the user authenticated indefinitely (or until
>   they manually logout).

You are hard coding the second parameter to `true` instead of using the value taken from the user input.

You are already setting the input to the $remember variable, so try passing that instead.

```
Auth::attempt($userData, $remember)
```

Comment: I already tried passing `$remember` as NULL in the way you suggested, but still it is not making it NULL in the db, instead it is generating some new encrypted string in db.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but I assume that it will still be setting the cookie even if you set the remember_me flag to `false`. The cookie will be set regardless but the value will be different.

Comment: Don't know, I tried it in all ways, but still not working. When I am logged in via Internet explorer with remember not checked, it generates a key and stores in db. I close the browser and re-open it and it shows me as logged in. Don't know how to set that particular column in table as null. Or invalidate remember sessions.

Comment: The cookies don't expire when the browser is closed by default. If you want that functionality you need to set it in the `app/config/auth.php` config file. Change the `'expire_on_close' => false,` line to `true`.